# the sampling distribution of sample means, why are samples taken with replacement?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, sampling-theory

I have what might be a silly question.  I am tutoring a family member in stats and I am trying to help her understand the sampling distribution of sample means, but I don't quite understand why it's derived the way it is myself.

The way I understand this particular distribution is *the distribution of sample means for all possible samples of size n*.  Her notes contain a simple example the teacher gave:

**Suppose we have a small population: {2, 4, 6, 8}.  Let's find all possible samples of size n = 2.**

I would think all possible samples of size two would be:

{2, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 8}, {4, 6}, {4, 8} and {6,8}

But according to the notes, there are 16 possible samples of size two, and they are taken with replacement.  For example, one of the possible samples is {2, 2} and {2, 4} is counted as a distinct sample from {4, 2}.  I don't understand why these are counted.  The sampling distribution of sample means is used in hypothesis testing.  Say you are testing a claim about the mean of adult male heights and you want to select a sample of size n = 10, you would not count the same individual 10 times.  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A sample, by definition is a sequence of draws from the population. The sample $\{2,4\}$ implies that $2$ is drawn before $4$, whereas $\{4,2\}$ implies the opposite. In problems where the draws are not independent, the order matter as it has implication for the probability distribution of the remaining elements to be drawn.